# Remove the halo effect of Google Map Heatmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I'm trying to add a layer of contour plot to a Google map by using its HeatMap API,since the idea of contour plot is quite similar to the HeatMap with weights.The problem is, as you can see from the image below, the rendering of heatmap come with some halo effects, i.e. each pixel actually has a circle of blueness, which I assume is for increasing the contrast with the central colour (e.g. the redness here). Is there a way to customise the rendering and remove this halo effects? No official documents has been found to achieve this, as far as I know.

[Google map Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWceq.jpg)

Comment: You can specify custom colours for the heatmap gradient, so you should be able to change that blue to anything else.  What does your JS code look like?

Comment: @duncan Yes, I understand how to customise gradient, but I think the halo effect was generated automatically for each point at a given coordinate (lat, lon). Actually, you can see this by zooming in to a single point and the color of that point is not monochrome (i.e. it comes with gradient already). I took Google's example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap) for illustration at the moment.

Comment: @duncan I should also mention that, for a normal contour plot, we expect a single pixel or a point has a unique value, representing a unique colour intensity, instead of having edge effects which will affect the overall view. I hope I understand this in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to the gradient in use on that example:

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#HeatmapLayerOptions):

> gradient | Type:  Array
>   The color gradient of the heatmap, specified as an array of CSS color strings. All CSS3 colors are supported except for extended named colors.

It is set to:

```
var gradient = [
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
    'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
    'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
    'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ]
```

Which is blue for the smaller entries.  If you don't want blue, remove the blue,  this is just shades of red with different opacities:

```
var gradient = [
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ]
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uLw2L7uj/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example requires the Visualization library. Include the libraries=visualization
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization">

var map, heatmap;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {
      lat: 37.775,
      lng: -122.434
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: getPoints(),
    map: map
  });
  var gradient = [
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
  ]
  heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
}


// Heatmap data: 500 Points
function getPoints() {
  return [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783206, -122.440829),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783273, -122.440324),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783316, -122.440023),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783357, -122.439794),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783371, -122.439687),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783368, -122.439666),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783383, -122.439594),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783508, -122.439525),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783842, -122.439591),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784147, -122.439668),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784206, -122.439686),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784386, -122.439790),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784701, -122.439902),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784965, -122.439938),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785010, -122.439947),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785360, -122.439952),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785715, -122.440030),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786117, -122.440119),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786564, -122.440209),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786905, -122.440270),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786956, -122.440279),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800224, -122.433520),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800155, -122.434101),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800160, -122.434430),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800378, -122.434527),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800738, -122.434598),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800938, -122.434650),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801024, -122.434889),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800955, -122.435392),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800886, -122.435959),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800811, -122.436275),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800788, -122.436299),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800719, -122.436302),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800702, -122.436298),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800661, -122.436273),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800395, -122.436172),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800228, -122.436116),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800169, -122.436130),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800066, -122.436167),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784345, -122.422922),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784389, -122.422926),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784437, -122.422924),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784746, -122.422818),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785436, -122.422959),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786120, -122.423112),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786433, -122.423029),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786631, -122.421213),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786660, -122.421033),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786801, -122.420141),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786823, -122.420034),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786831, -122.419916),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787034, -122.418208),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787056, -122.418034),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787169, -122.417145),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787217, -122.416715),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786144, -122.416403),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785292, -122.416257),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780666, -122.390374),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780501, -122.391281),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780148, -122.392052),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780173, -122.391148),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780693, -122.390592),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781261, -122.391142),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781808, -122.391730),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782340, -122.392341),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782812, -122.393022),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783300, -122.393672),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783809, -122.394275),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784246, -122.394979),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784791, -122.395958),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785675, -122.396746),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786262, -122.395780),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786776, -122.395093),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787282, -122.394426),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787783, -122.393767),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.788343, -122.393184),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.788895, -122.392506),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.789371, -122.391701),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.789722, -122.390952),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.790315, -122.390305),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.790738, -122.389616),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.779448, -122.438702),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.779023, -122.438585),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778542, -122.438492),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778100, -122.438411),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777986, -122.438376),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777680, -122.438313),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777316, -122.438273),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777135, -122.438254),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776987, -122.438303),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776946, -122.438404),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776944, -122.438467),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776892, -122.438459),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776842, -122.438442),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776822, -122.438391),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776814, -122.438412),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776787, -122.438628),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776729, -122.438650),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776759, -122.438677),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776772, -122.438498),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776787, -122.438389),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776848, -122.438283),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776870, -122.438239),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777015, -122.438198),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777333, -122.438256),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777595, -122.438308),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777797, -122.438344),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778160, -122.438442),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778414, -122.438508),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778445, -122.438516),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778503, -122.438529),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778607, -122.438549),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778670, -122.438644),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778847, -122.438706),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.779240, -122.438744),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.779738, -122.438822),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780201, -122.438882),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780400, -122.438905),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780501, -122.438921),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780892, -122.438986),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781446, -122.439087),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781985, -122.439199),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782239, -122.439249),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782286, -122.439266),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.797847, -122.429388),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.797874, -122.429180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.797885, -122.429069),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.797887, -122.429050),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.797933, -122.428954),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.798242, -122.428990),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.798617, -122.429075),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.798719, -122.429092),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.798944, -122.429145),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799320, -122.429251),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799590, -122.429309),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799677, -122.429324),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799966, -122.429360),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800288, -122.429430),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800443, -122.429461),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800465, -122.429474),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800644, -122.429540),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800948, -122.429620),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801242, -122.429685),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801375, -122.429702),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801400, -122.429703),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801453, -122.429707),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801473, -122.429709),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801532, -122.429707),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801852, -122.429729),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.802173, -122.429789),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.802459, -122.429847),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.802554, -122.429825),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.802647, -122.429549),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.802693, -122.429179),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.802729, -122.428751),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766104, -122.409291),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766103, -122.409268),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766138, -122.409229),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766183, -122.409231),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766153, -122.409276),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766005, -122.409365),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765897, -122.409570),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765767, -122.409739),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765693, -122.410389),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765615, -122.411201),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765533, -122.412121),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765467, -122.412939),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765444, -122.414821),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765444, -122.414964),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765318, -122.415424),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.763961, -122.415296),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.763115, -122.415196),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.762967, -122.415183),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.762278, -122.415127),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761675, -122.415055),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.760932, -122.414988),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.759337, -122.414862),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.773187, -122.421922),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.773043, -122.422118),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.773007, -122.422165),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772979, -122.422219),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772865, -122.422394),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772779, -122.422503),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772676, -122.422701),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772606, -122.422806),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772566, -122.422840),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772508, -122.422852),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772387, -122.423011),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772099, -122.423328),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.771704, -122.423783),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.771481, -122.424081),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.771400, -122.424179),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.771352, -122.424220),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.771248, -122.424327),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.770904, -122.424781),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.770520, -122.425283),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.770337, -122.425553),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.770128, -122.425832),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.769756, -122.426331),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.769300, -122.426902),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.769132, -122.427065),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.769092, -122.427103),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.768979, -122.427172),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.768595, -122.427634),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.768372, -122.427913),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.768337, -122.427961),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.768244, -122.428138),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.767942, -122.428581),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.767482, -122.429094),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.767031, -122.429606),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766732, -122.429986),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766680, -122.430058),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766633, -122.430109),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766580, -122.430211),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.766367, -122.430594),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765910, -122.431137),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765353, -122.431806),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764962, -122.432298),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764868, -122.432486),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764518, -122.432913),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.763435, -122.434173),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.762847, -122.434953),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.762291, -122.435935),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.762224, -122.436074),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761957, -122.436892),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761652, -122.438886),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761284, -122.439955),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761210, -122.440068),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761064, -122.440720),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761040, -122.441411),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.761048, -122.442324),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.760851, -122.443118),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.759977, -122.444591),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.759913, -122.444698),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.759623, -122.445065),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.758902, -122.445158),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.758428, -122.444570),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.757687, -122.443340),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.757583, -122.443240),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.757019, -122.442787),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.756603, -122.442322),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.756380, -122.441602),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.755790, -122.441382),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.754493, -122.442133),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.754361, -122.442206),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.753719, -122.442650),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.753096, -122.442915),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.751617, -122.443211),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.751496, -122.443246),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.750733, -122.443428),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.750126, -122.443536),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.750103, -122.443784),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.750390, -122.444010),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.750448, -122.444013),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.750536, -122.444040),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.750493, -122.444141),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.790859, -122.402808),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.790864, -122.402768),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.790995, -122.402539),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791148, -122.402172),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791385, -122.401312),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791405, -122.400776),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791288, -122.400528),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791113, -122.400441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791027, -122.400395),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791094, -122.400311),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791211, -122.400183),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.791060, -122.399334),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.790538, -122.398718),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.790095, -122.398086),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.789644, -122.397360),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.789254, -122.396844),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.788855, -122.396397),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.788483, -122.395963),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.788015, -122.395365),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787558, -122.394735),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787472, -122.394323),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787630, -122.394025),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787767, -122.393987),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.787486, -122.394452),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786977, -122.395043),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786583, -122.395552),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786540, -122.395610),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786516, -122.395659),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786378, -122.395707),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786044, -122.395362),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785598, -122.394715),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785321, -122.394361),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785207, -122.394236),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785751, -122.394062),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785996, -122.393881),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.786092, -122.393830),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785998, -122.393899),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785114, -122.394365),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785022, -122.394441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784823, -122.394635),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784719, -122.394629),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785069, -122.394176),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785500, -122.393650),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785770, -122.393291),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785839, -122.393159),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782651, -122.400628),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782616, -122.400599),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782702, -122.400470),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782915, -122.400192),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783137, -122.399887),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783414, -122.399519),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783629, -122.399237),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783688, -122.399157),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783716, -122.399106),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783798, -122.399072),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783997, -122.399186),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784271, -122.399538),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784577, -122.399948),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784828, -122.400260),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784999, -122.400477),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785113, -122.400651),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785155, -122.400703),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785192, -122.400749),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785278, -122.400839),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785387, -122.400857),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785478, -122.400890),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785526, -122.401022),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785598, -122.401148),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785631, -122.401202),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785660, -122.401267),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.803986, -122.426035),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.804102, -122.425089),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.804211, -122.424156),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.803861, -122.423385),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.803151, -122.423214),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.802439, -122.423077),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801740, -122.422905),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.801069, -122.422785),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.800345, -122.422649),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799633, -122.422603),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799750, -122.421700),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799885, -122.420854),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.799209, -122.420607),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.795656, -122.400395),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.795203, -122.400304),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778738, -122.415584),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778812, -122.415189),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778824, -122.415092),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778833, -122.414932),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778834, -122.414898),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778740, -122.414757),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778501, -122.414433),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778182, -122.414026),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777851, -122.413623),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777486, -122.413166),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777109, -122.412674),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776743, -122.412186),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776440, -122.411800),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776295, -122.411614),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776158, -122.411440),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.775806, -122.410997),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.775422, -122.410484),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.775126, -122.410087),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.775012, -122.409854),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.775164, -122.409573),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.775498, -122.409180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.775868, -122.408730),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776256, -122.408240),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776519, -122.407928),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776539, -122.407904),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776595, -122.407854),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.776853, -122.407547),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777234, -122.407087),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.777644, -122.406558),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778066, -122.406017),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778468, -122.405499),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.778866, -122.404995),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.779295, -122.404455),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.779695, -122.403950),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.779982, -122.403584),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780295, -122.403223),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780664, -122.402766),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781043, -122.402288),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781399, -122.401823),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781727, -122.401407),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781853, -122.401247),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781894, -122.401195),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782076, -122.400977),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782338, -122.400603),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782666, -122.400133),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783048, -122.399634),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783450, -122.399198),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.783791, -122.398998),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784177, -122.398959),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784388, -122.398971),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784404, -122.399128),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784586, -122.399524),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.784835, -122.399927),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785116, -122.400307),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785282, -122.400539),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.785346, -122.400692),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765769, -122.407201),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765790, -122.407414),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765802, -122.407755),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765791, -122.408219),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765763, -122.408759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765726, -122.409348),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765716, -122.409882),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765708, -122.410202),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765705, -122.410253),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765707, -122.410369),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765692, -122.410720),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765699, -122.411215),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765687, -122.411789),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765666, -122.412373),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765598, -122.412883),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765543, -122.413039),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765532, -122.413125),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765500, -122.413553),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765448, -122.414053),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765388, -122.414645),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765323, -122.415250),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765303, -122.415847),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765251, -122.416439),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765204, -122.417020),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765172, -122.417556),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765164, -122.418075),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765153, -122.418618),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765136, -122.419112),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765129, -122.419378),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765119, -122.419481),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765100, -122.419852),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765083, -122.420349),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.765045, -122.420930),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764992, -122.421481),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764980, -122.421695),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764993, -122.421843),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764986, -122.422255),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764975, -122.422823),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764939, -122.423411),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764902, -122.424014),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764853, -122.424576),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764826, -122.424922),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764796, -122.425375),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764782, -122.425869),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764768, -122.426089),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764766, -122.426117),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764723, -122.426276),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.764681, -122.426649),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782012, -122.404200),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781574, -122.404911),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.781055, -122.405597),
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.780479, -122.406341),
  ];
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. You solved the problem, but not for my original intention. For those who might be interested, I think I misunderstood the "weight" property here, which is just used to weight the colour intensity. A normal contour plot comes from a 3-D vector with a format like [lat, lon, value], where the "value" is not equal to the "weight" of the Google HeatMap. It actually refers to the colour but the colour intensity.